# Ссылка на объект в статическом методе

Tags: java, указатели

К примеру есть класс:

```
public class mclass {
    private static Stage stage=null;
    public static void set (Stage pstage) {
        stage = pstage;
    }
}
```

И классов, подобных этому, несколько. В таком случае, в метод `set()` будет передана ссылка на объект, или его копия? Иначе говоря, если передать один раз `pstage`, то при изменении этого объекта где-либо будет изменяться и `stage` в классе `mclass`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) в таком случае в метод `set()` будет передана ссылка на объект, или его копия?

Будет передана копия ссылки (по значению). В Java все аргументы передаются при вызове по значению.

> Иначе говоря, если передать один раз `pstage`, то при изменении этого объекта где-либо будет изменяться и `stage` в классе `mclass`?

Если изменить состояние объекта (поля), то да, `stage` тоже поменяется.

---

*Подробнее можно почитать в «Подробное рассмотрение особенностей передачи аргументов» в [полном руководстве](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/) по Java авторства Герберта Шилдта*:

> Когда методу передается ссылка на объект, сама ссылка передается способом вызова по значению. Но поскольку передаваемое значение ссылается на объект, то копия этого значения все равно будет ссылаться на тот же самый объект, что и соответствующий аргумент.